# Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery (CI/CD) for Smart Contract Development with Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am setting up private ethereum (Quorum) and I am trying very hard to see if one could setup a Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery (CI/CD) infrastructure for Smart Contract Development?

Currently I am using truffle to compile and migrate my smart contract to quorum. I wish to automate that process.

Has anyone done CI/CD with solidity?

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to just have Jenkins or Circle or Travis run a migration if tests succeed. All you would need is key(s) on the CI server with enough ether.

Comment: An easy solution is to run a `ganache` server before tests and shutdown when tests are complete. Another solution involves running a private instance with parity/geth (both have a development chain that can be used for that).

Comment: Right. What is ganache specified role in ci/cd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is to use ganache, a test blockchain to run tests, I prefer to use the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/ and migrate the contracts to the container and then run tests.

Although you can migrate contracts through CI/CD, unless you are using a test network such as ropsten, rinkeby or kovan, I would migrate contracts to main net manually because it costs eth. I don't know if quorum has any test networks.

Comment: thanks! I am looking and exploring how one can push smart contracts seamlessly across different testnets and mainnets -- any idea would be great

Comment: Consider looking into the Gorli testnet  https://www.ethnews.com/the-goerli-testnet-has-arrived, it is suppose to be a universal testnet